# String(format: の使用方法について

Tags: swift, xcode, string

Swiftで以下のコードを書くとエラーが出ます。何が悪いのでしょうか。

```
let name = "John"
let age = 25

let message = String(format: "名前：%s、年齢：%d歳", name, age)
print(message)
```

エラー

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb441d7742da526b0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

文字列を表すフォーマット指定子は`%s`ではなく、`%@`です。なので

```
let message = String(format: "名前：%@、年齢：%d歳", name, age)
```

で動くと思います。

Comment: [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)。リンク先の変換表を付け加えると、より親切な回答になるかと思います。